# In SwiftUI, how do I pass a a NavigationSplitViewVisibility to a subview?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview, navigationsplitview, navigationsplitviewvisibility

My app uses a NavigationSplitView to provide a 3 column (sidebar, content, detail) layout.  The sidebar is implemented in one view (SideBarView).  The content view is implemented in a separate view (ContentView).  When an entry (Server) in the sidebar is selected, it is passed down to ContentView as a parameter to its initializer.  All of this works great.

Now I want to give ContentView the ability to programmatically change the NavigationSplitView's columns using an instance of NavigationSplitViewVisibility.  Somehow I need to pass the NavigationSplitViewVisibility instance from SideBarView down to ContentView.  How do I do this?

I seem to get caught up in the fact that NavigationSplitViewVisibility does not conform to the ObservableObject protocol.

```
struct SideBarView: View {
    @State var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .automatic
    @State private var selectedServer: Server?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility, sidebar: {
            List (selection: $selectedServer, content: {
                //More SwiftUI Code here
            }
        }
    }, content: {
        if let server = selectedServer {
            // Here is where I want to pass columnVisibility to ContentView so
            // that it can update the configuration of the NavigationSplitView
            // within SideBarView
            ContentView(server: server)
        }
    }, detail: {})
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var server: Server
    
    init(_with aServer: Server) {
        server = aServer
    }
}
```

Comment: "the fact that `NavigationSplitViewVisibility` does not conform to the `ObservableObject` protocol" Are you sure that is what the error says? The error should be that `Server` does not conform to `ObservableObject`. Is `Server` a struct or a class? Can you show the declaration for `Server`?

Comment: Observations: in `ContentView`, you probably should have `let server: Server` not  `@ObservedObject ` since you declare 
`@State private var selectedServer: Server?`. 
To "...pass columnVisibility to ContentView so that it can update the configuration of the NavigationSplitView within SideBarView" 
 in `ContentView` use a `@Binding var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility` and pass it using 
 `ContentView(server: server, columnVisibility: $columnVisibility)`. Note you can remove `init(...)` in ContentView.

Answer (score 0):

Same was as you pass down read/write access to any `@State` value, with `@Binding var`, e.g.

```
ChildView(server: $server, columnVisibility: $columnVisibility)

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var server: Server // assumes Server is struct which it normally would be in Swift.
    // let server: Server // if you only need read access.
    @Binding var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility
    ...
```

Remember and use `let` if you only need read access. In either case, `body` is called when the value has changed since the last time the `View` was init.